# Monitor multiple logs files for same error or warning in geneos

Tags: geneos

I wanted to know how can I monitor same error or waning in multiple file in geneos. Basically I want to put a regex in log file name so that I setup one monitoring which monitors multiple log file for me.

For e.g 
I have file say 123_abc.txt , 123_def.txt , 123_ghi.txt and I want to setup a single monitoring to monitor all 123*.txt file for say keyword error or warning

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using wildcard (*) to monitor multiple files the defined key or ignore key will already be checked on all files (123*.txt)